# Interpreting coefficients of beta regression

Tags: r, regression, beta-regression

I have implemented a beta regression and am a little confused on how I should interpret the coefficients of my model. For context, both my independent variables and dependent variable are expressed in percentage form, ranging from [0, 1]. The only exception is one independent variable which takes the binary value of 0 or 1. Also, I used a logit link. Does anybody mind sharing how I could interpret the coefficients here in this beta regression? I've never worked with a dataset like this before; any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a statistical question, so you may have more luck on CrossValiated, which is the stats area. That said, you may find these links contain helpful information: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/J_02.html https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2021/11/08/beta-regression-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You interpret a logit-link beta regression output in a same way that you would interpret a logit-link logistic regression. We are modelling the expectation of the Beta-distributed Random Variable $Y$, via a logit link. Your model is something like:

$$
\text{logit} ( E[Y] ) =  b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + \cdots 
$$

Let's say that $x_1$ is your $[0,1]$ proportional predictor, and $x_2$ is your binary predictor.

**Interpretation of $x_1$**: it's probably not useful to do the usual "an increase in $x_1$ by 1 results in a ..." interpretation. You may want to say something like "and increase in $x_1$ by 1 percentage point (i.e. 0.01) results in an increase in the odds by a factor of $\exp(0.01 \times b_1)$."

**Interpretation of $x_2$**: basically a standard interpretation: "$x_2 = 1$ (or whatever the class label is) corresponds to an increase in the odds by a factor of $\exp(b_2)$".